# How to disable right-click pop-up menu in Pages Dock?

Tags: mac

[image]

How do I disable the app Pages from showing my most recent documents? In fact, I'd like to disable this little menu popup every time I right click on ALL of my apps.

Edit: I apologize for not clarifying. You see those documents (e.g. Purg2, Purgh), they are no longer on my desktop, I upload them into my computer with a scan disk and edit them using Pages. The problem here is that I don't want them visible every time I right click with my mouse or use two fingers on my trackpad when the Pages document isn't even on my computer.

Comment: Then what do you want the right click to do?

Comment: What is it you object to? You can set the Recent Items to None in System Preferences > General. But right-clicking on a Dock item will always bring up some kind of menu. That's an inherent part of the OS.

Comment: I apologize for not clarifying. You see those documents (e.g. Purg2, Purgh), they are no longer on my desktop, I upload them into my computer with a scan disk and edit them using Pages. The problem here is that I don't want them visible every time I right click with my mouse or use two fingers on my trackpad when the Pages document isn't even on my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for *recent items* not to show on an application's *dock tile*, you'll need to do at least two things, as also shown in the images below.

1. First in **System Preferences** > **General**, set e.g.: **Recent items: 10 Documents, Apps, and Servers** to : **Recent items: None Documents, Apps, and Servers**
2. Next, In Pages, as well as other apps that have an **Open Recent** *menu item* on the app's **File** *menu*, click **Clear Menu** in order for them not to show after taking the first step.

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]